# Different behaviors between headed and headless puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

On adidas.com the following code returns a 403 in headless but not in headed, yes I  know this has been asked before, no previous solutions work.

```js
resolve((async (url) => {
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--enable-features=NetworkService", "--ignore-certificate-errors"]
  });
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36');
  let body = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML);
  await browser.close();
  return body;
})(url))
```

Comment: How do I pass this?

Comment: You could install xvfb and run `xvfb-run node myscript.js` (Linux only, possibly Mac)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.  Do you know what caused this issue though?

Comment: Yes they are likely using a xhr to fingerprint you. Headless can be detected by inspecting window objects.